# Angular: Reference object in template

Tags: angular

I have:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="vortexFeed">
  <agm-marker
      *ngFor="let m of mVortex; let i = index"
      (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
      [latitude]="m.lat"
      [longitude]="m.lng"
      [label]="m.label"
      [markerDraggable]="m.draggable"
      (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">

    <agm-info-window>
      <strong>Alert</strong>
    </agm-info-window>

  </agm-marker>
</ng-container>
```

Instead of "Alert" I want m.class. How can I reference the "m" object?

Comment: Well, using `m`. `{{ m.class }}`. You already using `m` everywhere. Why would it be different here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace Alert with {{m.class}}

Answer (score 2):

if you want to output the `m.class` property you can use

```
 <agm-info-window>
  <strong>{{m.class}}</strong>
</agm-info-window>
```

more infos on string interpolation in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)